# Issue while converting string to DateTime in Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, python-polars

I am converting string column into datetime column...

Here is my input,

```
col
00000001011970
00000001011970
00000001011970
...
00000001011970
```

Here is my snippet,

```
df[col].with_column= df.with_column(pl.col(col).str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',strict=False).alias('parsed EventTime') )
```

this above snippet is not converting into DateTime...
the output is same as input... there is no change in output.

Please help me to convert string column to DateTime in polars.

Comment: if you have date/time represented as `00000001011970`, I'd not expect`fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` to produce the correct result

Answer (score 1):

Your format clause should match the input.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
"col": ["00000001011970", "00000001011970", "00000001011970"]
})
print(df.with_column(
    pl.col('col')
    .str
    .strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt='%S%M%H%d%m%Y',strict=False)
    .alias('parsed EventTime')
))
```

gives me

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ col            ┆ parsed EventTime    │
│ ---            ┆ ---                 │
│ str            ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 00000001011970 ┆ 1970-01-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 00000001011970 ┆ 1970-01-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 00000001011970 ┆ 1970-01-01 00:00:00 │
└────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Using this version

```py
print(pl.__version__)
```

```
0.14.26
```

Comment: df[col].with_column= df.with_column(pl.col(col).str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt='%S%M%H%d%m%Y',strict=False).alias('parsed EventTime')), i've executed but its not converting

Comment: It ought to be reproducable, at least with Python 3.9.13

Answer (score 0):

To add to 4pi's answer in the context of your comment...

polars is not pandas so you don't assign columns of existing dfs with `df['col']=` and you especially don't do it with `df['col'].with_column`

`with_column` means to keep everything there is plus add this other thing or if it's the same name as something that already exists then replace it with this.

That is in contrast to `select` which means to only give you what you ask for.

You can use the syntax of replacing the whole df like this

```
df = df.with_column(pl.col('col').str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt='%S%M%H%d%m%Y',strict=False).alias('parsed EventTime'))
```

`polars` AFAIK is smart enough not to copy anything when you do this so although the syntax implies it's inefficient, it is efficient.

If you were replacing a column then you could use the `replace` method ie.

```
df.replace('col',df.get_column('col').str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt='%S%M%H%d%m%Y',strict=False))
```

It's not clear from your question if you're trying to add a column called `parsed EventTime` or if you're trying to replace the existing `col`.

You can also replace columns with the first syntax...

```
df=df.select(pl.col('col').str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt='%S%M%H%d%m%Y',strict=False))
```

since there's only one column in this df, you would get the same result from

```
df=df.with_column(pl.col('col').str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt='%S%M%H%d%m%Y',strict=False))
```

Comment: df.replace(col,df.get_column(col).str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt='%S%M%H%d%m%Y',strict=False)), I got output as 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000

Comment: can i get in this format 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: I don't know there is a global option to make date times print in that format by default.  You can do a strftime on the column with %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S to get that string output though